# catch a handled exception in a library?

Tags: c++, exception, point-cloud-library

I am working with point cloud library and it has a handled exception which is thrown when there is no model to fit.

I do not want to see their message in my log, I cannot catch it again as it has already been caught via pcl.

is there a way in C++ to workaround this issue and stop their message?

Comment: nope. you'll need to either edit the code and recompile the library, prevent the cause of the exception or use a different library.

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that the library throws an exception and it is caught before reaching your code? And you want to change that behaviour? To change the behaviour of the library, you'll need to modify the source code of the library.

Comment: @RichardHodges Editing the log at the end is easier I think.

Comment: @user2079303 yes you are right.